# Массив и string

Tags: pascal

Мне нужна помощь, имеется массив и имеются значения (v[1]:='Вова'; и т.д) как мне сделать так чтобы при чтении b он сравнивал со всеми значениями массивов?

```
program hack;
uses crt;
var a,b,f:string;
c:longint;
d,e,i:integer;
v:array[1..10] of string;
begin
      v[1]:='Вова';
      v[2]:='вова';
      v[3]:='Вовка';
      v[4]:='вовка';
      v[5]:='Вован';
      v[6]:='вован';
      v[7]:='Володя';
      v[8]:='володя';
      v[9]:='Владимир';
      v[10]:='владимир';
      textbackground(lightmagenta);
      clrscr();
    delay(750);
      sound(400);
    delay(245);
      writeln('Вы мальчик или девочка?');
      nosound();
      readln(a);
    delay(500);
      writeln('Ты ',a);
    delay(1000);
      writeln('А как тебя зовут, ',a,'?');
      readln(b);
```

Comment: Напишите цикл. *(1 символ нужен...)*

Comment: Игорь, а какой именно?

Answer (score 1):

```
found: boolean;
...
found := false;
for i := Low(v) to High(v) do
begin
  if v[i] = b then
  begin
    found := true;
    break;
  end;
end;

if found then
begin
  writeln('Hi, ' + b + '!');
end
else
begin
  writeln('do not know you, go away');
end;
```